# Connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365/2016 Web-API

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm trying to execute the following API Call

```
RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest
```

I'm trying to follow [this steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt770386.aspx), but I can't replicate the code I get a bunch of errors.

I have installed Dynamics 365 HelperCode successfully but starting managing the code I don't get why is not working. (I have 0 experience on C#)

```
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples.HelperCode;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

private HttpClient httpClient;


private void ConnectToCRM(String[] cmdargs)
{
    Configuration config = null;
    if (cmdargs.Length > 0)
        config = new FileConfiguration(cmdargs[0]);
    else
        config = new FileConfiguration(null);
    Authentication auth = new Authentication(config);
    httpClient = new HttpClient(auth.ClientHandler, true);
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.ServiceUrl + "api/data/v8.1/");
    httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}



Program app = new Program();
try
{
    String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
app.ConnectToCRM(arguments);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{ ; }
finally
{
    if (app.httpClient != null)
    { app.httpClient.Dispose(); }
}


private static void DisplayException(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    while (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t* {0}", ex.InnerException.Message);
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }
}
```

**The errors**

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: Your code does not appear to be encapsulated in a class

Comment: Something like this 
`namespace connector
{ class Project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you missed the important thing: **Follow instructions.**

In the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt770386.aspx) link you refer, these are crucial but basic steps. Read & Follow religiously as you replaced the readily available class & Main method it seems, thats why breaking.

> 1.In the Solution Explorer, open Program.cs for editing.

&

> 1.Edit the Program.cs file.
>
> 2.Add the following property to the Program class.
>   This property will be initialized after a successful connection to a Dynamics 365 server.
>
> `private HttpClient httpClient;`
>
> 3.In the Main method, add the following statements.

Keep the `class Program{}` & `static void Main()` untouched. I advise you to read a good tutorial on .net and c#